# Python/RE Parse tnsnames.ora into connection strings

Tags: python, regex

I’m developing a function to retrieve particular connection strings from tnsnames.ora and set them for use by cx_Oracle later. I decided that learning ‘Regular Expression’ would be the right approach, but it’s giving me more trouble than I thought. Any help collapsing each entry into a single line with no spaces and matching the entries is appreciated.
Snipet from tnsnames.ora file:

```
ExPRD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExPRD)
    )
  )

ExQAT =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExQAT)
    )
  )

ExTST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExTST)
    )
  )
```

Desired result, set the following global variables:

```
exprd_cs = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= whatever.com)(PORT=0000))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= whatever2.com)(PORT=0000))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ExPRD)))
extst_cs = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= whatever.com)(PORT=0000))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= whatever2.com)(PORT=0000))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ExTST)))
```

Python Script:

```
import re

tns_file = path/tnsnames.ora

def Read_File(FILENAME, LINE): 
    try:
        if LINE == 'NO':
            with open(FILENAME) as opened_file:
                file_string = opened_file.read()
        if LINE == 'YES':
            with open(FILENAME) as opened_file:
                file_string = opened_file.readline()
    except IOError as e:
         print("File Failed to Open;", e)
         raise e
    except Exception as e:
         print("Read File Failed;", e)
         raise e
    return file_string

def Get_TNS_Config():
    global exprd_cs
    global extst_cs
    tns_config = Read_File(tns_file, 'YES')
```

(Find a way to collapse config entries into single line no spaces)

```
(continued...)
    for match in re.finditer(r'<db>=<db_cs>', tns_config):
        if match.group(1) == ‘ExPRD’:
            exprd_cs = match.group(2)
        if match.group(1) == ‘ExTST’:
            extst_cs = match.group(2)

Get_TNS_Config()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to get your variables could be to first create the lines without the spaces using [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub) and a regex that matches one or more times a whitespace character with a negative lookahead that asserts that what follows is not `ExPRD`, `ExQAT` or `ExTST` at the start of the line  and replace with an empty string:

`\s+(?!^Ex(?:PRD|QAT|TST))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE1EAa/1)

Then use [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.finditer) using 2 capturing groups `^(Ex(?:PRD|QAT|TST))(.*)` where you could check for the first capturing group and assing the second capturing group accordingly.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YBPFza/2/)

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/DPFFX75762)

For example

```
tns_config = """ExPRD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExPRD)
    )
  )

ExQAT =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExQAT)
    )
  )

ExTST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = whatever2.com)(PORT = 0000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ExTST)
    )
  )"""


regex = r"\s+(?!^Ex(?:PRD|QAT|TST))"
result = re.sub(regex, '', tns_config, 0, re.MULTILINE)
exprd_cs = ""
extst_cs = ""

if result:
    for match in re.finditer(r'^(Ex(?:PRD|QAT|TST))(.*)', result, re.MULTILINE):
        if match.group(1) == 'ExPRD':
            exprd_cs = match.group(2)
        if match.group(1) == 'ExTST':
            extst_cs = match.group(2)

print(exprd_cs)
print(extst_cs)
```